# Using search and replace to remove line breaks in Open Office

Tags: find-and-replace, openoffice-writer

I've imported a document into Open Office and it has a number of hard returns in wrong places. In MS Word, I could use the search and replace to simply get rid of them all easily, but Open Office's search won't find them. I tried /n with the 'use regular expressions' box  checked, but it seems that only looks for 'shift-enter' breaks and not ordinary hard returns.
Is there another way to remove them all quickly, or do I have to go manually through the document and remove each one individually. This is a surprising oversight for Open Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find & Replace in Writer can only search within a paragraph, but cannot search across a paragraph break.

You might give a try to the extension [Alternative dialog Find & Replace for Writer](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/AltSearch)
by Tomas Bilek, which is reported as capable of searching across paragraphs.

Comment: worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Click *More options* and select **Regular Expressions**, then use `$` in the find box to locate and select paragraph breaks.  If you do not put anything in the Replace box, it will delete them.  Or you could put a space in the Replace box.