# Removing all manual word / line breaks in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, linebreaks

I have auto word break option enabled in my Word 2010 so most of the words breaks correctly on the end of lines. When I'm not satisfied with the results, I can always press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to force that break.

When I want to revert such process, so resulting document would contain no words broken to other lines, first thing to do is to disable (turn off) auto word breaking feature.

But what about all these manual word breaks? How to get rid of them? I can search and replace all of them into empty strings, but I don't know what should I enter to Search & Replace box to find them?

All these manual word breaks are not visible in normal text flow. If I turn on displaying of invisible characters, then they appear as `¬` symbols. However copying and pasting such symbol into Search & Replace box brings no results, because Word is unable to find any of such, even though I have plenty of them in my document.

Is there any automated way of remove all manual word breaks or do I have to find and remove each of them manually?

(*question very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/233682/using-search-and-replace-to-remove-line-breaks-in-open-office), but covering Microsoft Word editor, not OpenOffice Writer*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace *Optional Hyphen* (`^-`) with an empty string:

[image: 1]